# What return syntax should be used in Python when calling a method on the object you wish to return?

Tags: python

I want to setup and return an input stream object I've defined in my program and I want a more succinct syntax for doing so if one is available.

The following code functions as intended and I've looked up various posts about this but none have described a way to succinctly perform a method on an object and then return it

```
def setup_input_stream(self) -> AbstractInputStream:

    self.midi_sender.connect(self.midi_note_reciever)

    input_stream: AbstractInputStream = None
    if (MidiInputStream.midi_input_avaliable()):
        input_stream = MidiInputStream(self.midi_sender)
    else:
        input_stream = KeyboardInputStream(self.midi_sender)

    input_stream.open()
    return input_stream
```

I would like something like the following but the open() method does not return the object itself (though they're custom so I could define the open function to do this if it's not considered bad style)

```
def setup_input_stream(self) -> AbstractInputStream:

    self.midi_sender.connect(self.midi_note_reciever)

    if (MidiInputStream.midi_input_avaliable()):
        return MidiInputStream(self.midi_sender).open()
    else:
        return KeyboardInputStream(self.midi_sender).open()
```

This program is based in Python 3.7 so it can use any new syntax available.
Thanks!

Comment: You can, if you make the `.open()` methods return the stream object itself.

Comment: If you can control the behaviour of `MidiInputStream.open`, then there is no problem in making it return the object.

Comment: There is otherwise no syntax available that lets you return a specific object after first calling a method on that object. Just be explicit.

Comment: if your goal is to shorten the code, you can use a ternary to decide which class to instanciate, instead of instantiating 2 different classes

Comment: „What return syntax should be used...“ The pythonic, explicit one where separate actions are separate statements.

Comment: create an helper function which opens the object passed in parameter then returns the object itself.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I'll have the stream objects `.open()` methods return the objects themselves!